# is there api in pip or other package can generate standard compatibilty string as the pypi index?

Tags: python

in pypi there is a name standard to general file name as py3-none-any and cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64

I wonder what is the standard, and which function is used to generate this?

Is there an api for this? I mean cp means cpython, pp means pypy, but there is also jpython and ironpython, what is the standard way to obtain the short name?

Comment: https://pypi.org/p/packaging